# DocuSign Signing with C# API

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi, e-signature

I would like to create DocuSign document with dynamic data from an C# application with Tables (which may contain 1 or more rows). I also need dynamic number of Users who need to sign the document. Since, dynamic data, how I let DocuSign know, which are the offset/co-ordinates for the signature.​

I was thinking of creating the PDF from word template thru OpenXML or some third-party application like Aspose, SautinSoft.

I'm not sure about how to let DocuSign know which co-ordinates to use for signing, because the co-ordinates will be in different places based on no. of rows as well as paging.

Please let me know whether this is possible, or better way of DocuSinging.

​I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [auto-place](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/) feature where you use anchor strings to determine where to place the tabs (Signing elements). They don't have to be in the exact location where the text shows on the document, it can be placed in proximity, within a specific number of pixels from the text you want.

So, this is dynamic in nature as it's based on the document, DocuSign scans the document to look for the text you want (which can also be hidden) and then places the tabs where you need them.